# Delay to drop menu with jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu

The menu I want to modify has this HTML structure:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="fashionmenu">
    <li class=""><a href="#">Home<a/></li>
    <li class=""><a href="about.html">About<a/></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

What I have tried to accomplish was a delay on the dropdown menu, I already have the Jquery code for it, but for some reason I can't understand (and here is where I kindly ask you to guide me) why on hover, even if has a nice smooth effect on hover , the menu doesn't retire unless I hover again on it. BUt , of course, I would want that whenever I move the mouse to a different menu item, the dropdown menu to retire by itself automatically.

Here is the javascript:

```
    $(function(){
      $('#fashionmenu > li > ul')
        .hide()
        .click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
      });


      $('#fashionmenu > li').toggle(function(){
        $(this)
        .removeClass('waiting')
        .find('ul').slideDown();
      }, function(){
        $(this)
        .removeClass('waiting')
        .find('ul').slideUp();
      });

    $('#fashionmenu > li').hover(function(){
      $(this).addClass('waiting');
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('#fashionmenu .waiting')
          .click()
          .removeClass('waiting');
          },300);
        }, function(){
          $('#fashionmenu .waiting').removeClass('waiting');
        });

    });
```

Thank you in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mwwFn/1/

```
$(function () {
  $('#fashionmenu > li > ul').hide().click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('#fashionmenu > li').toggle(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('waiting').find('ul').slideDown();
  }, function () {
    $(this)
      .removeClass('waiting')
      .find('ul').slideUp();
  });

  $('#fashionmenu > li').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('waiting').find('ul').slideDown();

  }, function () {
    $(this).removeClass('waiting').find('ul').delay(3000).slideUp();
  });

});
```

Comment: Chanckjh, thank you for the code, tried it now. It acts well on the first click but when I repeat the action it's like before, so strange. Additionally, all of the other menu items can't be clicked (so they take me nowhere even if the links are assigned). Do you think it might have something with the css, could there be any connection or are they 2 separate things? Thanks so much again.

Comment: do you really need the click function and did you really assigned a link to it? I don't think that the css is the issue.

Comment: updated jsfiddle by switching the toggle slideup slidedown: http://jsfiddle.net/mwwFn/2/

Comment: Yes, I assigned the links, when I remove the javascript the links work fine. I have to click on the other menu items yes, because it's the menu. The new code is better but the other menu links still don't work:( And the slow down effect is available only at the first hover, then it acts s if there was no javascript. I appreciate your support.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mwwFn/3/ now it works, but is the toggle function really necessary? You cant click on it because it will take you to an other site

Comment: No, no, I meant the other menu links, not the parent links. The toggle is not necessary. Now all links work with your latest code. It's almost perfect, I still don't know why on my page, the second time I hover the slow down effect dissapears, but I'll have to invetsigate it more because I see i your example it works just fine.

Comment: you probably still have this `$(this).removeClass('waiting').find('ul').delay(3000).slideUp();` delay(3000) makes it wait 3 seconds before it do something

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I only have your latest code, so it should be something else.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your issue... it might be solved with the well-known hoverIntend plugin:
https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent

Older but same purpose - DoTimeOut
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/hoverintent/

Comment: Could you please outline how a solution might look like? Links are so fleeting ... Thx!

Comment: Sorry, not in detail. There are a lot of blog articles/tutorials and even topics on stackoverflow, which explains the usage of this plugin. I just remembered and mentioned it, because it seems to be the defacto standard for this purpose. Its used a lot, so why re-invent the wheel ;-) I am no jQuery guru, just using plugins and make some modifications from time to time.